# datatable pagination in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.0
I am also using datatable jquery plugin to display grid.

Controller mehtod

```
 public function index() {

    $jobs = \App\Job::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->limit(1000)->get();

    return View::make('jobs.index', ['jobs' => $jobs]);
}
```

The issue:
Right now I hard-coded the ->limit(1000) to 1000 jobs in datatable grid to display
it but i have more then 1000 records to display.

What I want?
I want to display 500 records with grid and then 500 records.
I am not sure if there is any call back data-table plugin function available?
I need a dynamic way to load next 500

NOTE:
I am not willing to us this solution of scrolling 
https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html

Comment: There is a package for this https://github.com/ACFBentveld/Laravel-datatables

Comment: @WimPruiksma That link is not available anymore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can user ajax data source:

please visit : https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

Example PHP Script:

```
// function will process the ajax request
public function getMembers(Request $request) {

        $draw = $request->get('draw');
        $start = $request->get('start');
        $length = $request->get('length');


        $search = (isset($filter['value']))? $filter['value'] : false;

        $total_members = 1000; // get your total no of data;
        $members = $this->methodToGetMembers($start, $length); //supply start and length of the table data

        $data = array(
            'draw' => $draw,
            'recordsTotal' => $total_members,
            'recordsFiltered' => $total_members,
            'data' => $members,
        );

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Example JavaScript :

```
$('#all-member-table').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            url: base_url+"ajax/members"
            },
            "columns": [
            { data: '1' },
            { data: '2' },
            { data: '3' },
            { data: '4' },
            { data: '5' },
        ]
    } );
```

Example HTML:

```
<table id="all-member-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column1</th>
                    <th>Column2</th>
                    <th>Column3</th>
                    <th>Column4</th>
                    <th>Column5</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
  </table>
```

Comment: How about search and order by?

Answer (score 4):

I think above answer should be extended with search feature.

Update the answer;

```
$filter = $request->get('search');
$search = (isset($filter['value']))? $filter['value'] : false;
where('somecolumnonyourdb','like', '%'.$search.'%')
```

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use [standard pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#basic-usage):

```
$jobs = \App\Job::latest()->paginate(500);
```

Or [create it manually](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator).

Comment: I need a dynamic way to load next 500 records

Comment: @Peter so what's the problem? Just use ajax to load previous 500 or next 500 records using the same code I've shown.

Comment: I need to a logic to load next previous 500 records.So I am expecting some solutions..

Comment: There is a package for this https://packagist.org/packages/acfbentveld/laravel-datatables